# CSS Corner sharpened

Tags: css, cornerradius

I was wondering if it is possible to have an easy and clean purely CSS way to get a sharp corner on a object. At the moment i am working with a corner like this

```
.main navigation {
background-color: #14377d;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
border-right: solid #2d71ba;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px 25px;
width: 134px;
line-height: 25px;
text-align: left;
}
```

But this will make the corners rounded. What i would like to have is the bottom right corner cut of. Example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/usnZt.jpg]

Thanks all for taking the time to read this,

Sjoerd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use `clip-path` and `polygon()` for that:

```css
div {
  background-color: #2C2F33;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 70%, 80% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Basically how `polygon()` works is, you can define seperated by each comma an x-y-position: `polygon(x1 y1, x2 y2, ...)`. Using percentage with 100% being the full given width or height you can make any linear shape.

Comment: I think this will indeed do the trick now i have to play around with the percentage. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Possible this technique you would find useful for you: [Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/digitalmood/n50udoc9/). It's based on `polygon` function and `clip-path` property.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

`polygon(100% 0, 100% 75%, 90% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);`

Thanks! Getting my navigation on website close to where i want it to be!
[image: Thanks guys]